# how to create tabs with hidden content at the beginning, show up only when you click?

Tags: html, css, tabs

using css+html only create a click to expand tabs??

Comment: show some code, do some research see [help](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

This example will show you how to go about doing this:

```css
body {
  display: block;
}
.span3:focus ~ .alert {
  display: none;
}
.span2:focus ~ .alert {
  display: block;
}

.table{
  width:400px;
  height:200px;
  margin:50px auto;
}
.alert{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background:#e74c3c;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:40px;
  color:#fff;
  border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
  display:none;
}
.row{
  width:100%;
  height:40px;
  background:#e74c3c;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:40px;
  color:#fff;
  border-bottom:1px solid #fff;
}
.span3, .span2{
  padding:5px 7px;
  border:2px solid #e74c3c;
  color:#e74c3c;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <span class="span3" tabindex="0">Hide Me</span>
  <span class="span2" tabindex="0">Show Me</span>
  <br><br>
  <div class="row">
    #1
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    #2
  </div>
  <div class="alert">
    #3
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/6W7XD/6618/